# problem in sending html email using django

Tags: django, html-email

I am trying to send emails to my clients using django's `send_mail` function.
I have configured my email host using a gmail account.

This is how I send my email:

```
send_mail(cv.QT_CONFIRMATION_MAIL_TITLE[lan], cv.QT_CONFIRMATION_MAIL[lan].format(str(uid, encoding="utf-8"), token),
    'mygmail@gmail.com', [useremail], fail_silently=False,
    html_message=cv.QT_CONFIRMATION_MAIL[lan].format(str(uid, encoding="utf-8"), token))
```

this `html_message` has an anchor tag in it which links to the activation link. In gmail clients the link works, but when I try this in yahoo emails the link is empty.

it is shown in html like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow"> click here </a>
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is the mail going to spam? That seems to be the most likely issue as Yahoo strips all links from a message that is in spam.

Comment: Not an answer, but here's a warning: When I was learning how to send emails with django, I tried to send a message about 20+ times because I was trying to do it with the `celery` package from mysite to a yahoo email. I didn't have it configured right at the time. Long story short, yahoo server blocked all messages from mysite for about a month, because it was roughly the same message. That threw me off a ton. But if I sent emails directly from the account, and they were all different, it worked fine. So if you're going to do this, only send from an @yahoo to the same @yahoo, then play with it.

Comment: @solarissmokeno the mail doesn't go to the spams. it just removes the href in my mail. but when I dont provide `html_message` argument it is shown as it should be.

Comment: @discomushroom it is not the same mail. because the activation links are different and since the first time I sent it , the yahoo didn't show tha correctly. what should I do?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, but within the next couple weeks I will be testing, because I want the same thing. I made a pretty template, did it all inline and everything. As of this second I only know how to `send_mass_mail()`, and `send_mail()`, both with text only.